# sumproduct with with criteria on column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how to use sumproduct to produce a muliple and sumif please?  I would like the cell B17 '=B2*E2+B7*E7+B12*E12.

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$15=$A17)*(B$2:B$15)*(E$2:E$15))
```

Drag/Copy down formula as required and across to right for calculating `rate2` also if needed. See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((array1)*(ceriteria1)*(ceriteria2)*(ceriteria3)*(ceriteria n),(array2))
```